# How to open multiple files in a path skiiping files with a determined name

Tags: pandas, loops, python-xarray, gfs

I have a folder with files whose name goes from f000 to f168, and I would like to select only files above f000, that is, from f003, f006, to f168. How can I do this ?

The file name starts like this:

gfs.0p25.2020010100.f000.WE.grib2

Comment: You can pass a list to `open_mfdataset` rather than a glob string (assuming that’s what you’re asking about?). So you can simply exclude the paths you don’t want from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above, you can always filter the list of files before passing them to `open_mfdataset`:

```
import glob
import xarray as xr

files = glob.glob('/path/to/files/*grib2')
filtered = [f for f in files if 'f000' in f]

ds = xr.open_mfdataset(filtered)
```

Alternatively, you may be able to tune your `glob` string to do this automatically:

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('/path/to/files/*.f000.*.grib2')
```